# write a R routine with if and else if condition

Tags: r

```
support_cell<-function(I=2,J=2,zero,cell){
 output<-c(0,0)

 element<-c(zero[1], zero[2], cell[1], cell[2])
 if (any(element<1) || any(element[c(1,3)]>I) || any(element[c(2,4)]>J)) stop("cell elements out of bound")
 
  
    else if(cell[1]==zero[1] & cell[2]==zero[2]) {output}
    else if(cell[1]==zero[1] & cell[2]!=zero[2]) {output[2]=1 }
    else if(cell[1]!=zero[1] & cell[2]==zero[2]) {output[1]=1 }
    else {output[c(1,2)]=1} 

  return(output)
 }



#example 1

zero<-c(1,2)
cell<-c(2,2)

support_cell(I,J,zero,cell)
[1] 1 0
```

I wrote this function to compare two vectors and the output is another binary vector based on the comparison. The code is working fine but I know there should an easy and efficient way to rewrite this code. I want to know your methods as well.

Comment: You pass `I` and `J` in the function but don't use it. What is it used for? What are you trying to do ? When the output should be 0 vs 1?

Comment: Okay, this is a part of some big thing! it will be useful later, I did not want to remove it. Therefore I just set I=2 and J=2. 
Now I have edited my code for I and J!

Comment: When the output should be 0 or 1? Can you explain?

Comment: When the first(or second) element of **zero** matches with the first(or second) element of **cell** output should 0 if does not match output 1. Do not compare the first element to the second element!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `!=` to match if value of `zero` matches with that of `cell`. We return 0 for a match and 1 for no match.

```
support_cell<-function(I=2,J=2,zero,cell){
  output <- as.integer(zero != cell)
  return(output)
}
zero<-c(1,2)
cell<-c(2,2)

support_cell(I,J,zero,cell)
#[1] 1 0
```

Comment: Can you explain + and !zero? why plus sign?

Comment: `%in%` returns `TRUE`/`FALSE` values, `+` converts this logical values to integer 1/0 respectively. `!` is used to negate the values from `%in%`.

Comment: ```zero<-c(1,2)
cell<-c(2,1)

support_cell(I,J,zero,cell)
[1] 0 0
```

The result in this case should be 1,1.
I think your program gives incorrect result in this case! The first vector searches the value  in second vector. Not position-wise!!

Comment: Yes, I checked. And it worked. Your code helped me a lot, especially the latest one. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

You are simply trying to match the two vectors element-wise. R has that operation already vectorized:

```
x <- c(1,2,6,3,8,0,4)
y <- c(1,7,6,2,8,0,3)
+(x == y)
# [1] 1 0 1 0 1 1 0
```